# SELECT COUNT query throws error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database named webshop on localhost with several tables in it. When I run the query: `SELECT COUNT (userId) FROM users;`

It trows me the following error:

`FUNCTION webshop.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

I have no idea why, as the query seems fine to me, does anyone?

Comment: I got more wierd error message from SQL which I could not make how to proceed: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)"...  It helps if MySQL given meanigful suggestion along with error like what is indicated below answer - Remove the space before the opening parenthesis !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the space before the opening parenthesis

```
SELECT COUNT(userId) FROM users;
```

See [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html) (which, incidentally, is exactly what the error told you to do!)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the function COUNT or anny MySQL function without the space.

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(userId) FROM users;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of your space. MySQL is somewhat sensitive when it comes to functions.

```
SELECT COUNT(userId) FROM users;
```